# OpenCL: Struct within struct sending to internal function on device side

Tags: struct, opencl

Got a question about struct handling in OpenCL that I didn't find on here. I've gathered the all of the data I use in a struct, which itself consists of several structs. I want to do the following:

```
typedef struct tag_OwnStruct
  {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    int d;
    float e;
    int f;
  }OwnStruct;

typedef struct tag_DataStruct
  {
     OwnStruct g;
     //+ Alot of other structs... not written for simplicity

  }DataStruct;

void PrintOwnStruct(OwnStruct* g)
{
  printf("Current lane id : %f\n",g->a);
}

__kernel void Test(__global DataStruct *data)
{
  PrintOwnStruct(&data->g);

}
```

So I want, from the given data I get sent in from the host side to the device, to send the reference to a struct inside of it. That doesn't work somehow, and I don't know why. I've tried the same thing in plain C code and it worked..

If I change PrintOwnStruct to :

```
void PrintOwnStruct(OwnStruct g)
    {
      printf("Current lane id : %f\n",g.a);
    }
```

and call the function as : `PrintOwnStruct(data->g)` the code will run on the device side. Is there any other way to do this? Since I'm not sending the reference to the function, is it being passed by value? And shouldn't that be slower than passing function parameters by reference?

Comment: Are you using CL2.x or CL1.x? In CL 1.x this `void PrintOwnStruct(OwnStruct* g)` means that `g` is a `private` pointer - a different address space to `__global` - Try using `void PrintOwnStruct(__global OwnStruct* g)` [tho' one would hope that the compiler would give an error for that - I'm pretty sure the one I work with does, but I have a vague feeling that is not in standard clang, which is what 90% of OpenCL uses]

Comment: Please edit your question to use only one of the C or C++ tags, as they are separate languages.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: And technically, neither applies, since this is a question about the OpenCL C language, so OpenCL should be the correct tag. So edited.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Hi! I'm using CL1.2. But yes the __global addition worked well! Thanks for the quick answer! I think you can post this as an acceptable answer? By the way is it possible to get some kind of compilation error check for openCL? If i compile through the terminal using g++, or through Eclipse, I don't get any idea where the error is. It either builds the openCL kernel code or doesnt. So while developing I'm currently in the blind for syntax errors on the device side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem appears (from comments) to be the confusion between `__private` and `__global` address spaces, and possibly that the compiler/runtime is not very helpful in informing about the mix of pointers.

```
void PrintOwnStruct(OwnStruct* g)
{
  printf("Current lane id : %f\n",g->a);
}

__kernel void Test(__global DataStruct *data)
{
  PrintOwnStruct(&data->g);
}
```

The `__global DataStruct *data` is a pointer to something in `__global` address space [in other words having the same address for all CL threads], the argument to void `PrintOwnStruct` `OwnStruct* g)` declares an argument that is pointing to `OwnStruct` in the default `__private` address space [in other words on the stack of this thread].

The correct thing to do is to maintain the address space for both pointers to `__global` by declaring the function `PrintOwnStruct(__global OwnStruct* g)`.

I'm pretty sure SOME OpenCL compilers will give an error for this, but apparently not this one. I expect that true syntax errors, such as adding `%-&6` to the code will in fact give you a kernel that doesn't run at all, so when you call `clCreateKernel` or `clBuildProgram`, you'll get an error - which can be displayed by `clGetProgramBuildInfo`. But if the compiler isn't detecting different address spaces, then it's a bug/feature of the compiler.

[In fact, if your compiler is based on Clang, you may want to have a look at this bug:
https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19957 - half an hour of googling gives a result of some sort! :) ]

In the newer CL2.0 the default address-space is `generic`, which allows "any" address space to be used.

Comment: I should add that I tried the code in the question on my machine at work, and it does indeed give compile errors for the change of pointer type.

Comment: And a commit to the clang just now that should fix this - but of course, your CL Compiler may be several revisions before this. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/88c1b1051180ac861f39bb3dfc212613a17018cf